# get values from string using strsplit and/or substring in R

Tags: string, r

The below string character, contains information that i want to use and assign to variables.

`[1] "ELEV:    82 m  LAT:  39° 37' 39\" N  LONG:  22° 23' 55\" E"`.

For example: assign to a `ELEV` variable a numeric value equal to `82`.

How should i approach this? Do i need a regular expression using something like `strsplit`, `substring`?

Comment: And how do you want to deal with the other information? What structure do you want the final output in? It would help if you posted a more complete question so we don't have to guess at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, you need regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `strsplit` solution.

The first argument to `gsub` is the pattern string `"(\\w+):"` .  It matches "word" characters `"\\w"` ensuring that there is at least one such character `"+"` but this match succeeds only if those word characters are followed by a colon `":"`.

The second argument to `gsub` is the replacement string `":\\1:"`. It specifies that the portion of the pattern within parens `"(\\w+)"` is replaced by itself `"\\1"` followed by a colon `":"`.   That is, it prefaces each word ending in `:` with a `:`.

Finally `strsplit` splits on spaces-colon-spaces forming the result into a matrix.  The code does not depend on what the labels are:

```
m <- matrix(strsplit(gsub("(\\w+):", ":\\1:", x), " *: *")[[1]][-1], 2)
```

giving:

```
> m
     [,1]   [,2]             [,3]            
[1,] "ELEV" "LAT"            "LONG"          
[2,] "82 m" "39° 37' 39\" N" "22° 23' 55\" E"
```

or this alternative form:

```
v <- as.list(setNames(m[2,], m[1,]))
```

giving:

```
> v
$ELEV
[1] "82 m"

$LAT
[1] "39° 37' 39\" N"

$LONG
[1] "22° 23' 55\" E"
```

which can be used like this:

```
v$ELEV
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto Your solution works great too and i might go with it. It's not really fair that i unaccepted and accepted yours as an answer but for what i am trying to do your code works better.

Comment: @KapelNick, no problem. Gabor usually has some interesting approaches. I still prefer the directness of my approach though, particularly if you are dealing with data that has more than one line. :-)

Comment: Can you please provide some comments on the `regexp` part of your answer? ty

Comment: OK. Added some additional explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't get you the values as numeric, but it does clean up your string a bit. Here's an example with two similar lines of data:

```
String <- c("ELEV:    82 m  LAT:  39° 37' 39\" N  LONG:  22° 23' 55\" E",
            "ELEV:    100 m  LAT:  36° 37' 39\" N  LONG:  19° 23' 55\" E")
out <- read.table(text = gsub("(LAT:|LONG:)", "\n\\1", String), 
                 header = FALSE, sep = ":", quote = "", strip.white = TRUE, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out
#     V1            V2
# 1 ELEV          82 m
# 2  LAT 39° 37' 39" N
# 3 LONG 22° 23' 55" E
# 4 ELEV         100 m
# 5  LAT 36° 37' 39" N
# 6 LONG 19° 23' 55" E
```

Here's what's happening:

- The `gsub("(LAT:|LONG:)", "\n\\1", String)` part sort of fakes inserting a new-line character before each `LAT:` and `LONG:` is encountered.

  - In that, the `"\n\\1"` replacement basically says find the pattern and tack a `\n` onto it.
- The rest is basic `read.table` work.

  - Instead of a "file", we just read the text that we get after using `gsub`.
  - The `sep` is set to a colon (ELEV, LAT, and LONG are all followed by colons).
  - `strip.white` is added to take care of the extra whitespace.
  - `quote` is specified since you have embedded quotation marks.
  - There are no headers.
  - `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` will make your life easier later on.

From here, you can get a `list` if you wanted to quite easily:

```
split(out$V2, out$V1)
# $ELEV
# [1] "82 m"  "100 m"
# 
# $LAT
# [1] "39° 37' 39\" N" "36° 37' 39\" N"
# 
# $LONG
# [1] "22° 23' 55\" E" "19° 23' 55\" E"
```

That would make it easy to convert at least the `ELEV` values to numeric.

Comment: wow you are fast. Can you please explain your code? thank you sir

Comment: @KapelNick, Added an explanation. Hope it helps!